# CakePHP Auth login non sense

Tags: cakephp, authentication

I'm trying to make a simple login system for my users, but I can't figure out why it won't log me in, the Auth->login() method always returns FALSE (incorrect information) for some reason... might be something with password hashing.
I have cakePHP 2.5.2.

Here is a screenshot of my issue: [ISSUE](http://imgur.com/d0IftQn)

My beforeSave() method in **UsersController**:

```
public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
    $this->request->data['User']['password'] = Security::hash($this->request->data['User']['password']);
}
```

and the login() method:

```
function login() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('You\'ve successfully logged in.' . ' <b>' . $this->Session->read('User.login') . '</b>'), 'alert', array(
                'plugin' => 'BoostCake',
                'class' => 'alert-success'
            ), 'success');
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
            ////  $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        } else {
            // var_dump($this->Auth->user());
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Sorry, the information you\'ve entered is incorrect.'), 'alert', array(
                'plugin' => 'BoostCake',
                'class' => 'alert-danger'
            ), 'danger');
        }
    }
}
```

here's the Auth component:

```
public $components = array(
        'Session',
        'Auth' => array(
            'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'home'),
            'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'home'),
            'loginAction' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'),
            'authError' => 'You are not authorized to access this page.',

            'authenticate' => array(
                        'Form' => array(
                            'userModel'=>'User',
                            'fields' => array(
                                'username' => 'login',
                                'password'=>'password')
                        )
        ),
            'flash' => array(
                'element' => 'alert',
                'key' => 'auth',
                'params' => array(
                    'plugin' => 'BoostCake',
                    'class' => 'alert-danger'
                )
            ),'authorize'=>array('Controller'),
        )
    ,'DebugKit.Toolbar'
    );
```

Comment: Could you show use your `Auth` component settings? CakePHP is waiting for a `username` field not `login`.

Comment: added Auth component code where I specified the fields to Authenticate users

Comment: Move `beforeSave` inside your `User` model and try to use `SimplePasswordHasher` to hash the password instead of `Security::hash`. See this page http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html, I don't know where you saw that there were a `beforeSave` method in controllers.

Comment: I just saw that I already had a beforeSave method in my User model :/

Comment: I'm now using the beforeSave() method from the cakephp documentation in my User model, and it hashes the password when a user registers but it still fails when I try to login. This is confusing as hell!

Comment: Are you sure that's the `login` method which return `false` and not something else? Did you check that your `password` field is enough large to store a password (50 should be sufficient according to the doc).

Comment: Yep i checked the password field length aswell, but now I can see the query that it's generating the AND clause is missing

Comment: Can you put the query? CakePHP only query on `login`, the password is checked after.

Comment: The query to fetch user from db will only have condition for username not password. The password comparison is done in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's incorrect I removed everything and it works I don't know how

Comment: Even `$this->data['User']['password'] = $passwordHasher->hash($this->request->data['User']['password']);` seems incorrect. Why does your model have access to request object?

Answer (score 0):

Move your beforeSave method to your Model, not the Controller.
When saving data Cake looks for any functions that should run before inserting the data in your Model.

You will also need to create a new user (if you look in your database you should find that the password has been stored as plaintext because the hashing in the beforeSave would never have been called.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should provide the Security::hash() function blowfish or set the app's internal salt to true.

Like this:

```
public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
$this->request->data['User']['password'] = Security::hash($this->request->data['User']['password'], null, true); 
}
```

This is the way, the deprecated AuthComponent::password() function works.

Just tested it this way in my Cake App and it work's fine.

See http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-Security.html#_hash

Edit:
beforeSave() should be in the User's Model, not in the User's Controller